# How to assign and call variables from a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a text adventure game in Python 3.4, here is the code:

```
class Player:
def __int__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.maxhealth = 50
    self.health = self.maxhealth
    self.attack = 7

def main():
    print('1. Start')
    print('2. Load')
    print('3. Exit')
    option = input('--> ')
    if option == '1':
        start()
    elif option == '2':
        pass
    elif option == '3':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        main()

def start():
    print('Hello adventurer! What is your name?')
    option = input('--> ')
    global PlayerIG
    PlayerIG = Player(option)
    start1()

def start1():
    print ('Name:',PlayerIG)
    print ('Attack:',PlayerIG.attack)

main()
```

I keep getting this error everytime I run my code:

```
PlayerIG = Player(option)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I can't really wrap my head around it, please help. I want to know what I did wrong in assigning the variable from a class.

Comment: Change `__int__` to `__init__`.

Comment: Thank youuu. But now the output looks like this:                                    Name: <__main__.Player object at 0x000000000436E240>
Attack: 7. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you want to print the name of the player, why don't you print the name of the player? `print('Name:', PlayerIG.name)`

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that lol. Thank you, I'm still a beginner so this helps me a lot.

Comment: Main shouldn’t call itself. Use a while loop.

Comment: Please give a sample code, so I can understand clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to 
1. change the `__int__` to `__init__` and indent the `__init__`
2. When printing player name do PlayerIG.name.

Below is the correct code.

```
class Player:
      def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.maxhealth = 50
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.attack = 7

def main():
        print('1. Start')
        print('2. Load')
        print('3. Exit')
        option = input('--> ')
        if option == '1':
            start()
        elif option == '2':
            pass
        elif option == '3':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            main()

def start():
        print('Hello adventurer! What is your name?')
        option = input('--> ')
        global PlayerIG
        PlayerIG = Player(option)
        start1()

def start1():
        print ('Name:',PlayerIG.name)
        print ('Attack:',PlayerIG.attack)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was compiling different info from youtube tutorials and pdfs that I got really confused on what to do, this helps a lot.